# How to generate multiple JAR's from a project in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

Is there a way to generate multiple JAR files from a single project in Netbeans? Currently I have some packages that almost never change, but other parts that change more frequently. One solution is to split it into multiple projects, but I really like having them in one place (and it would probably also cause some difficulties with SVN etc.)

Is it possible to generate JAR files based on a list of packages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, Netbeans does not provide help for that, but it is possible if you write your own build.xml to include only whatever you want.

Usually, you would have one project per JAR, and have them separate project (since they don't change, they should also have their versionning space and number) You could extract the *never changing* classes and put them in separate projects, have them referenced by the main project, commit the main project (thus deleting the removed classes from the repository) then committing all other projects to SVN.

If you still insist on building your own build.xml to enable multiple JARs within the same project, it is possible, but I can't help you (I'd advise against it)